# VLC won't play back sound after after apply normal system updates

Tags: 12.04, sound

Everything was fine this morning until I routinely updated my 12.04.01 set up. However I just realized that my favorite player, `VLC` can't playback any sound whatsoever (be it mp3, flv, mpeg etc). Every other media player(SM Player, Rhthymbox, default movie player)  works fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try changing the volume on VLC ? It happened to me once, but when I changed the volume, it came back to normal.